# How to recognize repetition of tokens in jison?

Tags: javascript, parsing, yacc, jison

### TL;TR

The objective of this exercise is to detect the repetition of a certain token, I am trying to do it with the symbol * coming from Regex, but it does not work.

#### Problem description

I am doing a basic transpiler, it consists in translating certain syntax with already defined grammar. I still have some drawbacks when defining the detection of multiple tokens. That is, using * to specify the repetition of a regex token *(I think the `*` is used to define the repetition of a token)*, for example (see `SENTENCE*`):

```
 FUNCTION
   : DEF ID PAR_OPEN PAR_CLOSE
       SENTENCE*
     END
        { $$ = 'function ' + $2 + '(){' + $5 + '}' };

  SENTENCE
    : PRINT
    | VAR_ASSIGN
    |;
```

Grammar works with the input:

`def hello()
    println "dsasd"
end`

but it does not work with the entry:

`def hello()
    a = 3
    println "dsasd"
end`

The error thrown is:

`bash
Error: Parse error on line 3:
...llo()    a = 3    println "dsasd"end
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '+', 'OR', 'AND', '=', '<>', '-', '*', '/', '>', '<', '>=', '<=','^', 'PAR_CLOSE', '%', 'END', got 'PRINTLN'`

**Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

## [**See Gist complete code**](https://gist.github.com/juliandavidmr/5c545f8cc1fe58d19986625a7a17f756#file-grammar-jison-L117)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `%ebnf` to the grammar. See [here](https://github.com/zaach/jison/wiki/Deviations-From-Flex-Bison)